# i want to enable button when only validation is true in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, routes

i am new to reactjs developer,i want to disabled button by default.Enable button when there are no validation errors and then history.push routing should be done.please help me to sort out this issue.Thanks in advance

```
        onSubmit(e) {
         e.preventDefault()
    let formFileds = [
        "business_name",
        "therapeutic_area",
        "disease",
        "first_name",
        "last_name",
        "email",
        "phone_number",
        "cell_number",
        "fax_number",
        "address1",
        "address2",
        "city",
        "zipcode",
        "state",
        "country",
        "password"
    ];
        let isValid = true;
        formFileds.forEach(field => {
            isValid = this.validateField(field) && isValid;
        });

        if (isValid) this.setState({ isFormSubmitted: true });
        else this.setState({ isFormSubmitted: false });

//if validation error is occurred  then the below condition should not work,But routing is done even if the validation error message is displayed     
   register(newUser).then(res => {
   this.props.history.push(`/login`)
        
   //here it is the button
   <button type="submit" className="btn but  btn-block" disabled={!isEnabled} >Register</button>
```

Comment: Where are you setting isEnabled field?

Comment: Do you want your form fields validated before the form is submitted? or after? I'll give you a hint, you should probably validate them before submission if you want to be able to enable the submit button to submit the form and take any actions.

Comment: @DrewReese     yes please  give me a hint, i want to perform a validation before submit and then routing action should be done

Comment: You can validate form fields in `onChange` handlers and so long as all fields pass validation let the submit button be enabled and take the navigation action. If you provide a more complete code example ([MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) we can probably provide more assistance.

Comment: @ Drew Resse   here you can access to see the full code in this provided link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62512262/perform-validation-when-button-is-clicked-in-reactjs

Comment: Do you have a *current* codesandbox with the fix from that question applied to it?